# How to replace a row as column header in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My column headers are in row 4. How do I replace row 4 as my column header?

Basically my SQL Server is connected to an Excel file, the design of the source Excel is in such a way that there are two tables on top of each other. The last 50 columns between the two table match each other, hence why they are placed on top of each other.

Now once I connect to SQL, I'd like to replace the column header of the second table in row 4 as the primary header and combine the two tables. I'd like to try this without changing the structure of the source data in Excel. That is like the last option.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to load the excel file into a static table, name it as say main_table_stg. After that run command to load into a main target table as follows

```
insert into main_table
select *
  from main_table_stg
where header_row_column <> ='COLUMN_NAME'
```